# Brother and sister transmigrate to magical world but sister dies and brother starts a journey to look for a legendary spell to revive her

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

Brother and sister transmigrate after been hit by a trackto magical world.
The brother and sister meet a group of adventures and join the adventures guide.
They soon fight a dragon (western dragon) but sister dies she leaves and crystal of some kind and the brother the tales that crystal and starts a long journey to look for a legendary spell to revive her.

Can't remember the name of the manga. Searching every manga site trying to see if it could jog my memory but nothing has worked so far.
The manga is mostly black and white.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Are you sure there's not any extra info you could [edit] in to help track down what you're looking for? The checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) could help jog your memory. When did you read this? Does the brother look for the spell?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Do you remember how they transmigrated, i.e. did they die or fall in to a portal or something similar? Do you remember how the sister died in the new world? Are you positive she's dead and not just missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further details, this narrative sounds very similar to the core plot of Final Fantasy: Lost Stranger.

The story in question follows a young man and sister who both landed jobs at Square Enix to work on the final fantasy series. They end up getting hit by a truck and awakening in a fantasy world like the game they were helping develop. Complete with fantasy races they recognize, even though the names for the respective species didn't match what they were familiar with.

They join an adventuring group and the brother uses a bow but realizes his only real talent is the Libra ability that reveals hidden stats for creatures and lore in the world. I believe the ability is unique to only him as well.
His sister sadly is killed by a dragon in one of their first missions and revival magic is supposed to not exist in the world, but the Brother becomes convinced from his libra ability that there is a way to learn it still.

[image: Volume 1 cover FF:LS]

Comment: Thanks this is the one I was looking for

Comment: Even *Final Fantasy* is isekai now? What next? An isekai version of *I Am a Cat*?